# Get stored Zend_Auth data from outside the zend project (in an extern non-zend-project)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I'm working on a Zend project where I need to include another project, which isn't using ZF. This other project is stored in the public directory in the folder of the zend project.

For this other project I need the logindata from the zend project (zend auth is used for this). There are 2 ways to accomplish this i think.

1. Just get the stored login sessionvariable. *But where/what variable?*
2. Or try to get the data with zend methodes in the other project. *But how? Without changing the structure of this other project.*

Or maybe (probably) there's an other/better solution?!

Hope it's clear.
Tnx

Answer (score 1):

```
$authNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
$authNamespace->user = "myusername";
```

Just `include pathToZendProjectDirectory\Zend\Session.php` from your 'nonzend` project

Comment: Tnx for the response. I've tried this solution but the server doesn't find the requires inside the Session.php. Cause (I guess) the path of the requires (require_once 'Zend/Session/Abstract.php';) are always from the Zend directory. If I change all the paths to a relative path, then it may work, but it's a lot of work. :) There must be another solutions to fix this require problem.

Comment: If you add the Zend library directory to your include path in this other app, then you can just require in Zend/Session/Namespace.php and ZF will find all of the rest of the classes itself. Better still you could setup the autoloader.

Comment: Starting to feel dumb. ^^ My 'nonzend' project is in a folder in the public folder of the zendproject. So my include path to Session.php is '../../library/Zend/Session.php' or has it to be absolute? I've tried that as well, but it's still like the project can't use ZF 'to find' the requires.

Comment: @Tim Fountain nailed it: It is not sufficient to simply call `require_once '/path/to/Zend/Session.php';`. You'll want to add the library folder (the parent of the Zend folder) to the `include_path` in the non-ZF project. Then when you call `require_once Zend/Session.php`, all the subsequent includes/requires of Zend files will work.

Comment: Tnx all it's working. For the ones who just want to get the session (without any zf help), get a look at the $_SESSION['Zend_Auth'] array.

Comment: Hello @David Weinraub am pretty much interested in this solution. my problem was that my zf app is using ckeditor with pgrfilemanager in it. i need to secure the access of the pgrfilemanager using Zend_Auth. I would love to read your suggestions. thanks

Comment: @blacksensei: I'm not overly familiar with either package, but the general principle applies: it's best to put the `Zend` directory inside a directory that is on your app's defined `include_path` and use `Zend_Loader_Autoloader`. Whether you move your `Zend` directory or modify your `include_path` to point to its parent is, of course, up to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The login data is in SESSION variable. But we can't access the session data directly outside the project, because the SESSION contain some Zend objects. When we start the session it race an error __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer.
To over come this add the code in starting of the page.

```
function __autoload($class) { // required files load automatically
  require_once "pathToZendProjectDirectory/PathToZendLibrary/$class.php";
}
```