# How do I check Zend Sessions from an external directory (ZF2)

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 as well as a few external scripts.  These scripts are on the same domain, but just in a directory that doesn't use Zend.

I would like to ensure the scripts are only run by certain users, and would like to avoid another login. How can I view my Zend Sessions when these PHP files are not using Zend.  I did find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815710/get-stored-zend-auth-data-from-outside-the-zend-project-in-an-extern-non-zend-p) which appears to be in the right direction but the answer isn't helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Session Container from ZF2 with an external script without the framework...

The result of a Session Container is a "normal" session with a session id, so have a look to

```
session_id($sessionId);
session_start();
```

in your external script.